# foreach loop and variable undefiend in my case

Tags: php

http://viper-7.com/T1rkOL

what's wrong with $html variable below?

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,'a','b','c');
     echo "===numbers===".'<br>';
     $head = "===alpha===".'<br>';
$html;
foreach($arr as $item){
    if(is_numeric($item)){

            echo $item;
    }else{
        $html .= $item;
    }   
}
    echo $head . $html;
?>
```

what I want is like this

```
===numbers===
123
===alpha===
abc
```

Comment: You 've got wrong name of $html1 - it should be $html... :)

Comment: here you go you just had to define `$html1` http://viper-7.com/pzwmKK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `$html = "";`

Try like this:-

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c');

echo     '===numbers===';
echo     '<br />';
$head  = '===alpha===';
$head .= '<br />';

$html  = '';

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (is_numeric($item)) {
        echo $item;
    }
    else {
        $html .= $item;
    }
}

echo $head . $html;
?>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://viper-7.com/6WRHt1)**

Comment: rt he defines his variables

Comment: he updated his question to and defines his variables but now u got a working example - dafuq can't upvote -.-*

Comment: @ins0:- Yes initially the question was different but now I have posted the working example so that there remains no doubt.

Comment: i downvotes your first answer and now misclicked. please edit your answer so i can remove the downvote.sry

Answer (score 0):

Change `$html;` to `$html1 = "";`

you have to define your variable or set valuess to it.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `$html` but in the loop used `$html1`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
<?php 
 $arr = array(1,2,3,'a','b','c');
 echo "===numbers===".'<br>';
 $head = "===alpha===".'<br>';
$html = '';
foreach($arr as $item){
if(is_numeric($item)){

        echo $item;
}else{
    $html .= $item;
}   
}
echo $head . $html;
```

Added = ''; to $html definition, and changed $html1  to $html;

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $arr = array(1,2,3,'a','b','c');
         echo "===numbers===".'<br>';
         $head = "===alpha===".'<br>';
    $html1;
    foreach($arr as $item){
        if(is_numeric($item)){

                echo $item;
        }else{
            $html1 .= $item;
        }   
    }
        echo $head . $html1;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you defined `$html`, but never actually used it. Instead, you used `$html1`.

Having said that, your code would have worked, by "accident", if it wasn't for the fact the you only assign `$html1` under a certain condition. In the instances where the condition is not being met, that is where `$html1` is never defined. The solution, as you know, is to define `$html1` before the loop, so it is always defined regardless.